# Pg admin (postgresql) wont start

Tags: postgresql

I installed poster sql on my Mac. The first time I use it it works fine. The next time I want to open the application it crashes with te code EXC_BAD_ACCESS. How do I fix this?

I have tried to uninstall en re install the application and turned my computer off but this doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: What did you install on your Mac? The PostgreSQL server software or the pgAdmin-client software? And how did you do it? And what MacOS version?

Comment: Mac version is Sonoma
I downloaded the installer by EDB

Comment: I think its both pgadmin and postgresql

Comment: Try https://postgresapp.com to get PostgreSQL. It also installs the client psql for usage in the terminal. If you want some other client, just find something you like: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_Clients